# OpenGL: Loading rendered texture from Framebuffer objects

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, perspectivecamera, projection-matrix

I am doing a two-pass blur into a `framebuffer` object. To make sure that in the `FBO`, the whole scene is covered with the image I am trying to blur. Here is the process.

1. I have setup an `FBO` with the dimensions of the image I need to blur.
2. I am setting up an `Orthographic Projection` using the following function (called as `setupOrtho(FBO's dimensions)`  ):

   glViewport(0, 0, w, h)
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
   glLoadIdentity()
   glOrtho(0,1,0,1,-1,1)
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
   glLoadIdentity()
3. Draw to the `FBO`, using this projection. Unbind the `FBO` (back to the screen).
4. Switch to the `Perspective View` by calling 
   `setupPerspective(window's dimensions)` and replacing the `glOrtho` above with `glFrustum`.

If I draw simple white quads, the view switching works as expected. One quad is drawing in `Orthographic Projection` and other in a `Perspective View`. Now take the rendered texture from the `FBO` (let id be `RENDEREDTEXTURE`).

If I bind the `RENDEREDTEXTURE` in an `Orthographic Projection` in my main scene, it shows the blurred Image. If I bind it into the `Perspective View` in my main scene, the previously visible white quad (which was drawn in the `Perspective View`) disappears.

**SOLUTION**: Posted as an answer.

**NOTE** : Never forget MIPMAP generation when using textures.

What could be the issue here?

Please suggest any alternative means such that in the `FBO`, only the image I want to process on is visible (for which I did the orthographic projection), and in the main scene, the processed image is just like any other texture loaded from an image file.

Comment: Define "does not work". Does your GPU catch fire? Does it crash? Is the result incorrect?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz  Updated information.

Comment: I assume the code block above is also packed in a function like `setupPerspective`. Anyway, you could run your program trough gDEBugger and verify that indeed all the required state (matrices, FBO) are set back to the desired values before you render with perspective again.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Yes, it is. OK, I actually have a new development. The problem is NOT with the `View` matrices. I used `setupOrtho` and `setupPerspective`, and drew two quads. They were drawn as expected. When I bind the rendered texture into a quad in orthographic projection, it is shown with the blur I expected. But after switching to perspective matrix, without texture quad is drawn, but disappears if I bind the texture. What could be the problem here?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I am drawing into FBO using orthographic projection so that the whole Framebuffer is covered with the image I want to process and when I bind that into my main scene, it only feels like a simple loaded image. I hope you get what I am trying to do.

Comment: Uh. Oh. Well. Honestly, if indeed the texture has correctly rendered content, and just changing to the projection matrix makes it fail, while other texture content is properly drawn, I... have no idea what could be wrong. There must be something else you're missing.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I have updated the question with a clearer process of the problem I am actually facing.

Comment: I have only two tips I can possibly give you: `a)` create a fixed texture with some data and see if the problem still persists (narrow the problem to the simplest possible case of drawing the same, correct texture in both views). `b)` rewrite the thing to modern pipeline, discarding whatever might be not working here and hopefully making it work "just because". I am afraid that it would require more thorough debugging that's not particularly well suited for [so]; you won't paste your whole codebase here, after all. Try to bring that to an SSCCE so people could run the program themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `framebuffer` textures, `Mipmaps` are not generated automatically for the textures. They have to be manually triggered, after your `framebuffer` has rendered the scene you want.

Use the following snippet, right after you switch back to default framebuffer.

```
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, YOUR_FINAL_RENDERED_TEXTURE_ID)
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)
```

Then you can use `YOUR_FINAL_RENDERED_TEXTURE_ID` as you would normally to bind this texture anywhere.

Comment: From the sounds of things (blurring the framebuffer), you do not need mipmaps in the first place. They add 1/3 to the size of your storage and take unnecessary processing time to generate. The simpler solution would just be to use a more reasonable minification filter like `GL_NEAREST` or `GL_LINEAR` instead of the default `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`.